# Limits of sin and cos do not exist

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry, convergence-divergence, exponential-function

I'm asked to prove that $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \sin n$ and $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \cos n$ do not exist with the following steps:

1) prove that the two limits do not exist at the sam time, that is prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \cos n + i\sin n$ does not exist [tip: use $e^{i(n+1)}=e^{in}e^{i}$;

2) prove that if $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \sin n$ exists, than $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \cos n$ exists and viceversa;

3) conclude.

I've done point 2) but I'm not sure of my answer to point 1). Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{in}=l$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{i(n+1)}=l$, but this means that $e^i\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{in}=l$; in other words, $e^il=l$. Therefore, $l=0$, but this is impossible, since$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):\bigl|e^{in}\bigr|=1.$$